# Firebase query object key in array with Javascript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a db structure as:

```
user = {
 name: 'xxx',
 address: 'XXX YY ZZZ',
 updates: [
  {
    created: '09/03/2022',
    content: { message: 'Message #1132'},
    ....
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to query any user that have updates.content.message contains the word 'Message' with firebase web version.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like a fun use-case, but it's rather broad for us to answer without seeing what you tried already. So if you tried something already, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If not, this is probably the best place to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @Sy Quoc, Are you using Realtime Database or Firestore?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Im trying to find among users who have the update in updates that update.content.message have words : "Test"

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB No Im using normal firestore

Comment: @Sy Quoc, i've posted an answer. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Hi @SyQuoc, Have you tried the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

There's no native `like` query on Google Cloud Firestore. But you can manage to create a workaround using nodejs/javascript. See code below:

```
var collection = "user";

// search input. you can change this to any word like in the comment you said that you want to find document that contains "test".
search = "Message";

// gets the length of the search input.
searchLength = search.length;

// logically change the last character of the search input to imitate the `like` query.
searchFront = search.slice(0, searchLength-1);
searchEnd = search.slice(searchLength-1, search.length);
// will result to "Messagf".
end = searchFront + String.fromCharCode(searchEnd.charCodeAt(0) + 1);

const query = db
.collection(collection)
.where('updates.content.message', '>=', search).where('updates.content.message', '<', end)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});
```

The above code will search the `updates.content.message` that contains the word 'Message'. I leave some comments on the code for a better explanation. I'm not sure though if you're using `Firestore v8` or `v9` but the above code is written on `v8`.

**Result:**

```
drh13VT3T6n5bBHNARYD  =>  {
  address: 'XXX YY ZZZ',
  name: 'xxx',
  updates: { created: '09/03/2022', content: { message: 'Message #1132' } }
}
```

Comment: This is a good effort but will not produce the result the OP wants. They were specific in stating the results were for fields that *contains the word 'Message'* (note: *contains*) and this solution will only find fields that start with the word *Message*